# Joining a pivot table and a normal table to create a graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am having a hard time building dynamically a graph that results of joining together a pivot table summarizing some data, and a data field from another table, both sharing a common primary key/column.

Adding an image to make it clearer https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfAEo.png

the data summary (pivot table) is fine, but i dont' seem to be able to join it with the team capacity (little table B) to have it represented in the graph. The idea is to plot in the same graph each team's capacity coming from table B besides the sum of efforts for both committed and uncomitted jobs that comes from the  pivot

So far, i've only managed to copy the pivot table into a normal table and add a column with a VLOOKUP, but i need it to be dynamic without the manual copy. Surely there must be a smarter way to do it ?

How would you go about it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @iarzzz working with more that one table is a common & popular practice,,,, but structure wise your TABLEs are  not fit for the job,,, RELATION can be stablished between tables for further execution including graph making,,, so first re structure both the tables ,, then SET RELATION ,, next make PIVOT TABLE and finally the GRAPH !! **My suggestion is [edit] the post as sooner to avoid Down Vote to Close the post !!**

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use XLOOKUP or VLOOKUP to add the capacity to the effort table:

Assuming the small table is called 'capacity', then the formula in 'Capacity' column in top table would be:

```
=XLOOKUP([@Team],capacity[Scrum],capacity[TeamCapacity])
```

And you can create the pivot like this:

[image]

And the pivot chart is simply this:

[image]

Though I appreciate that duplicating the capacity for each value of status may not be ideal.

Another option might be to forgo using a pivot table and use a formula, something like this:

```
=LET(
groups, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(effort,{1,4})),
mapped, MAP(TAKE(groups,,1),INDEX(groups,,2),LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(FILTER(INDEX(effort,,3),(TAKE(effort,,1)=x)*(INDEX(effort,,4)=y))))),
result, VSTACK(HSTACK(groups,mapped),HSTACK(TAKE(capacity,,1),EXPAND({"capacity"},ROWS(capacity),1,"capacity"),TAKE(capacity,,-1))),
SORT(result,{1,2},1)
)
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

Then you can just create a normal bar chart:

[image]

And format it whatever way you want.

Comment: Very very nice sir